# Reference a list with letters

Tags: lists, labels, ref

I defined `parlist` using lower case letters for the items (I know that there are other ways to use letters for the items but I wanted to customize the list style anyway).

Unfortunately, if I refer to them, the label is printed with a number. Can anyone help me with that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{num}
\newenvironment{parlist}{\begin{list}{(\alph{num})}{\usecounter{num} \leftmargin0pt \itemindent5pt \topsep0pt \labelwidth0pt}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\begin{parlist}
    \item This is the first item \label{first}
    \item and another one
\end{parlist}   

As seen in \eqref{first}...
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel rarely holds out the promise of substantial rewards. Thus, rather than try to bend the very-low-level LaTeX environment called `list`to my specific needs, I would load the `enumitem` package and issue the following commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{parlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[parlist]{label=(\alph*),wide=0pt,topsep=0pt}
```

You may verify for yourself that this setup produces the exact same output as your version of `parlist`, in terms of the layout of the list-like environment. There's a big difference, though: The output of `\ref` is now what you expect it to be too, viz. `(a)`, etc.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % '10pt' is the default
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

%\newcounter{num}
%\newenvironment{parlist}{\begin{list}{(\alph{num})}{\usecounter{num}%
%    \leftmargin0pt \itemindent5pt \topsep0pt \labelwidth0pt}}{\end{list}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{parlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[parlist]{label=(\alph*),wide=0pt,topsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{parlist}
    \item This is the first item \label{first}
    \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{parlist}

As seen in \ref{first}, \dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Redefine `\thenum`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{num}
\renewcommand{\thenum}{\alph{num}}
\newenvironment{parlist}
 {%
  \begin{list}{(\thenum)}{%
    \usecounter{num}%
    \leftmargin0pt
    \itemindent5pt
    \topsep0pt
    \labelwidth0pt
  }%
}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\begin{parlist}
    \item This is the first item \label{first}
    \item and another one
\end{parlist}

As seen in \eqref{first}...
\end{document}
```

[image]